# Are $\{(x,0) \in \mathbb{R^2} : x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ and $\{(x,\frac{1}{x}) : x >0\}$ separated?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, separation-axioms

Our definition of separation is:

> If $C$ is a subset of a metric space, then $(A, B)$ is a separation of $C$ if $C = A \cup B$, $A \neq \varnothing$, $B \neq \varnothing$, and we cannot have that $\{x_n\} \in A$, $x_n \to x$, with $x \in B$ (and also vice versa).

Considering the $2$ sets $\{(x,0) \in \mathbb{R^2} : x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ and $\{(x,\frac{1}{x}) : x >0\}$ (assuming they are $A$ and $B$ as in the definition, and the union of them is $C \subset \mathbb{R}$), the shortest distance between them is $0$, which seems like it would imply that they "meet" at some point, because the distance between them is possible to be $0$, as $x \to \infty$. I don't have any intuition about sequences for this, so how can I tell if these two sets are separated or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Show that every point $\langle x,0\rangle$ of $A$ has an $\epsilon$-ball around it that is disjoint from $B$. In that case can any sequence in $B$ converge to $\langle x,0\rangle$?

Comment: If I choose the radius of the $\epsilon$-ball around every point in $A$ to be $< \frac{1}{x}$, is that enough to say that every $\epsilon$-ball is disjoint from $B$? If so, I don't see why there cannot exist a sequence in $B$ that converges to a point in $A$ (or rather, why disjoint neighborhoods imply that sequences in one cannot converge to another in general)

Comment: @ᴇʏᴇs: You have to be a little more careful than that: you need the radius to be at most the distance from $\langle x,0\rangle$ to the hyperbola, which is less than the vertical distance $\frac1x$. There can’t be a sequence in $B$ converging to a point of $A$ for the simple reason that every point of $A$ has a nbhd disjoint from $B$. If a sequence in $B$ converged to some $a\in A$, then every nbhd of $a$ would contain points of $B$.

Comment: If we want the distance to be at most $\frac{1}{x}$, doesn't strictly $< \frac{1}{x}$ fulfill that requirement?

Comment: @ᴇʏᴇs: We don’t want it to be at most $\frac1x$: we want it to be at most the distance fro $\langle x,0\rangle$ to the hyperbola, which is less than $\frac1x$. Specifically, it’s the distance from $\langle x,0\rangle$ to the point $p$ on the hyperbola where the tangent line is perpendicular to the line from $\langle x,0\rangle$ to $p$.

Comment: Since the tangent line at any point $p$ on the hyperbola is given by $-\frac{1}{x^2}$, I have to find the equation of a line perpendicular to this on the $x$-axis? Do I need to perform an integration to find the length of this (straight) curve?

Comment: @ᴇʏᴇs: Finding the point of the hyperbola closest to $\langle x,0\rangle$ and its distance from $\langle x,0\rangle$ is actually rather messy; I wouldn’t even try. Show that the open box $$(0,2x)\times\left(-\frac1{2x},\frac1{2x}\right)$$ is an open nbhd of $\langle x,0\rangle$ that does not intersect the hyperbola.

Comment: I've never worked with "open boxes" before. Is it okay to just have an open ball with radius $< \frac{1}{2x}$? Or can you provide a reference (textbook, website, etc.)

Comment: @ᴇʏᴇs: Ah, okay; I was assuming that you knew that the usual metric topology on $\Bbb R^2$ is the same as its product topology as the product of two copies of $\Bbb R$. Yes, any open ball at $\langle x,0\rangle$ that fits inside that box works just as well.